# Tomcat 8 configure multiple SSL connectors

Tags: java, ssl, tomcat, ssl-certificate, tomcat8

I have a single instance of tomcat server that has 2 services, each one is running on a different port:

```
<Service name="service-1">

    <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
           connectionTimeout="20000" 
           redirectPort="8443"  maxThreads="300" />
    <Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" />

    <Engine name="service-1" defaultHost="localhost" >

    <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
         resourceName="UserDatabase"/>

    <Host name="localhost"  appBase="service-1"
        unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true"
        xmlValidation="false" xmlNamespaceAware="false">


    </Host>
  </Engine>
</Service>

<Service name="service-2">

  <Connector port="8181" protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
           connectionTimeout="20000" 
           redirectPort="8443" maxThreads="300" />
           
  <Connector port="8099" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" />

  <Engine name="service-2" defaultHost="localhost">

    <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
         resourceName="UserDatabase"/>

    <Host name="localhost"  appBase="service-2"
        unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true"
        xmlValidation="false" xmlNamespaceAware="false">


    </Host>
  </Engine>
</Service>
```

These 2 service work on: [{public-ip}:8080/service-1](http://localhost:8080/service-1) and [{public-ip}:8181/service-2](http://ocalhost:8181/service-2).
Now, I want to install an SSL certificate on this server to secure connection to both endpoints, how can I do that? All related answers I've found uses a single connector on port 8443:

```
<Connector connectionTimeout="20000"
    acceptCount="100" scheme="https" secure="true"
    port="443" clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS"  
    keystoreFile="PATH_TO_KEY_STORE"  
    keystorePass="KEY_STORE_PASS"  
    keyAlias="KEY_STORE_ALIAS"/>
```

but I need to use multiple connectors instead.

Comment: In most questions people have just one service configured. Just configure a HTTPS connector separately in each service (obviously on different ports).

Comment: You need to use multiple connectors why? You can only have one connector on port 8443, and that's where you are redirecting all the other ports to, and that's where you need to have the certificate. You don't have certificates on plaintext ports. I don't see the point of your question.

Comment: @user207421 Because I have 2 wars deployed on same tomcat instance, each war is a service that is accessed on a different port. So, I cant redirect all ports to 8443. Instead, I want both ports to be secure by installing the certificate on the service connector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just changed connector for both services like so:

```
<Connector port="8080" maxHttpHeaderSize="8192" maxThreads="100"
           minSpareThreads="25" maxSpareThreads="75"
           enableLookups="false" disableUploadTimeout="true"
           acceptCount="100" scheme="https" secure="true"
           SSLEnabled="true" clientAuth="false"
           sslProtocol="TLS" keyAlias="server"
           keystoreFile="cert.jks"
           keystorePass="password" />
```

and

```
<Connector port="8181" maxHttpHeaderSize="8192" maxThreads="100"
           minSpareThreads="25" maxSpareThreads="75"
           enableLookups="false" disableUploadTimeout="true"
           acceptCount="100" scheme="https" secure="true"
           SSLEnabled="true" clientAuth="false"
           sslProtocol="TLS" keyAlias="server"
           keystoreFile="cert.jks"
           keystorePass="password" />
```

and now my endpoints work on HTTPS.